# Drop inactive features in Keras

Tags: python, keras, neural-network, deep-learning, sequential

I'm building a Sequential NN model in Keras for binary classification. The training data has about 600,000 rows and 2,000 features, so every epoch and every layer is very time consuming. I believe many of the features are not relevant to the model, and can be dropped altogether, to make the model thinner, so it it would be faster to work with.
I run a simple model with one hidden-layer of 200 neurons. How can I tell which of the features (which are actually the nodes in the input layer) are meaningless, so I could drop them from the data set and re run the model without them?

Answer (score 0):

There is a very big topic in machine learning called `feature selection`. Though, neural networks are considered to automatically choose the best features for the problem, to an extent, by using their weights, to either consider more or less some of them. Neural networks also need a lot of experience to be tuned correctly. I would definitely suggest you to increase the layers of the network, because you have a lot of data and features and use `l1 regularisation`, in order to get **sparse** weights and exclude most of the features. Also, these information are indicative, since I do not know anything about your dataset and your network architecture. At last, I would suggest you to study more about the basics of machine learning and then continue learning about neural networks, before practicing with real data.

Comment: Tnx, but my idea was to use this simple model to get rid of many of the (non-helping) features, so I can run much more complexed models with fewer features, and therefore saving a lot of running time.